# How can i make controller component for Form Element

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

In react native I want to make a dynamic controller component. But i cant access errors with it. I using "react-hook-form" for form elements. So Its my component :

```
 const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: {errors},
    setValue,
  } = useForm();
    const DynamicController = ({req, pattern, name, label}) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Text style={[t.textBase]}>{label}</Text>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              rules={{
                required: {
                  value: true,
                  message: 'Bu alan boş bırakılamaz!',
                },
              }}
              render={({field: {onChange, onBlur, value}}) => (
                <Input
                  errorText={errors[name].message}
                  error={errors[name]}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  placeholder={label}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
              name={name}
            />
          </>
        );
      };
```

My Input Component is basicly simple input. My problem is when i give error name like that example i cant access errors.

Its how i use my component :

```
<DynamicController
              label="Email"
              name="Email"
              pattern={true}
              req={true}
            />
```

When i dont fill the element and log the submit its not showing any error. Its simple passing validate. So what can i do where do i make wrong ? thank you for answerings!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Input a custom wrapper? If not, a better way do this using react-hook-form would be:

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: {errors},
    setValue,
  } = useForm(
  defaultValues: {
      firstName: '', // form fields should be populated here so that the error can be displayed appropriately 
      lastName: ''
    }
);
    const DynamicController = ({req, pattern, name, label}) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Text style={[t.textBase]}>{label}</Text>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              rules={{
                required: {
                  value: true,
                  message: 'Bu alan boş bırakılamaz!',
                },
              }}
              render={({field: {onChange, onBlur, value}}) => (
                <Input
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  placeholder={label}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
              name={name}
            />
             {errors[name] && <Text>This is required.</Text>}
          </>
        );
      };
```